# Alternative way to Range.GetSpellingSuggestions to recognize the correct word

Tags: vba, ms-word, spelling

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions, if the word is spelled correctly, Selection.Range.GetSpellingSuggestions.Count Returns 0, but there are cases when the word is spelled incorrectly and there are no suggestions, i.e. count=0, which is problematic.

Is any better way to know that the word is spelled correctly?

Just to note Application.CheckSpelling(aWord.Text) function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite easy, really. For example:

```
Sub HiLiteSpellingErrors()
Dim Rng As Range, oSuggestions As Variant
For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.Range.SpellingErrors
  With Rng
    If .GetSpellingSuggestions.Count > 0 Then
      .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    Else
      .HighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    End If
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

With the above code, spelling errors for which there are no suggestions are highlighted Green, and those for which there are suggestions are highlighted Yellow.

To process just a Selection, change 'ActiveDocument' to 'Selection'. Likewise:

```
MsgBox Selection.Range.SpellingErrors.Count
```

will return a simple count of spelling errors in a Selection.

Comment: Unfortunately this code is not working well for Russian. For instance, if you try it on this text "Евгений Евланов евмыхт еволюциемрэ европейские", It marks the fourth word spelled correct, when it is not.

Comment: The answer is correct for the problem as described. The issue is your failure to properly specify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After many experiments I found an answer
.
Application.CheckSpelling  works just for one language even if other languages proofing tools are installed.

You should specify desired language: Application.CheckSpelling(MyWord.Text, , , "Russian")

If different languages are used in the text,  you can't find errors using Application.CheckSpelling in one Run.